# TextView with HTML content - Hide images/empty squares

Tags: android, textview

I have html content and setting this into (android) textbox as follows

```
textbox.setText(Html.fromHtml(myhtml));
```

HTML content contains some img tags as well, I do not want display images, currently it displays empty square boxes where ever there is a img tag. How do I hide those square boxes?

Comment: Just remove this <img> tag from your HTML file.

Comment: I receive the html content from internet from various sources; it may not be well formed; so do not want to mess up string parsing and replacing

Comment: so, another way is you need to create one regular expression with <img></img> and remove all the <img> tags from your content and then you load that content into your textview.

Answer (score 4):

You could do a regex replace `<img.+?>` on `htmlString.`

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString.replaceAll("<img.+?>", "")));
```

Untested

**Update:**

since images can look like:

```
<img ...></img>
```

and

```
<img... />
```

This solution will match both cases:

```
String htmlBody = htmlString.replaceAll("<img.+/(img)*>", "");
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlBody));
```

Answer (score 3):

This works

Create Html.ImageGetter to return empty image as follows

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Html;

public class EmptyImageGetter implements Html.ImageGetter {
    private static final Drawable TRANSPARENT_DRAWABLE = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        return TRANSPARENT_DRAWABLE;
    }
}
```

and then create a static instance

```
private static final EmptyImageGetter EMPTY_IMAGE_GETTER = new EmptyImageGetter();
```

set this into text view

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myhtml, EMPTY_IMAGE_GETTER, null));
```